# Function take as an argument other function and few other arguments. Bind arguments to nested function and return recieved function

Tags: javascript, bind

```
function bindFunction(fn, ...array) {
    let args = Array.from(arguments);
    function F() {
        return args;
    }
    return F.bind(bindFunction);
}
```

nested function,
which outer function takes as a first parameter,
must to bind other parameters to nested function
and return them

Comment: That's not how `bind` works. The only thing `bind` does is change the value of `this` and you are not using `this` anywhere in your code

Comment: @slebetman Actually, `bind()` can also bind regular arguments. Its first argument binds `this`, the rest bind the first N positional arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
function bindFunction(fn, ...array) {
  return fn.bind(null, ...array);
}
```

Comment: Exactomundo! Thank you brother, this is works perfect.

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Comment: can you please explain, why you pass 'null' as a first parameter to a bind method?

Comment: Sure. The first argument is the function context (the value of `this` keyword inside the new function). You can also bind the context if you need it.